# Статья о U-Net с ResNet encoder

Tags: нейронные-сети, компьютерное-зрение

Часто замечаю как используют нейронную сеть U-Net с ResNet encoder. Но при поиске статьи, в которой впервые предлагается такое модифицирование модели у меня возникли сложности.
Мне необходимо это для научно-исследовательской работы. Все что я находила - это статьи где предлагают добавлять skip-connections блоки.
Возможно вы знаете необходимую мне статью и вам не составит труда помочь мне.
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Для таких вопросов лучше в сообщество ods.ai обратитесь, очень уж специализированный вопрос, тут мало специалистов по нейросетям.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо за совет, обращусь к данному сообществу, надеюсь помогут.